# Is it possible to stream a video from client side to nodejs server and save it to a mp4 file?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, stream

hello everyone thanks for reading this , is it possible to send video stream from client side to nodejs server then save it to a file each time there is a new chunk of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readable.pipe()` and `readable.unpipe()` functions to achieve this. Here is a small example

```
const writable = fs.createWriteStream("<filename>");
res.unpipe(writable)
```

Here your response will serve as the readable stream and can be unpiped into the new writable stream you have created.